# Якщо to filter перекладається як цідити, то використання слова цідити замість фільтрувати це пуризм?

Tags: вживання-слів

> [ПУРИЗМ](http://litopys.org.ua/ukrmova/um79.htm) (франц. purisme, від лат. purus — чистий) — крайній вияв
>   турботи про чистоту літературної мови, культуру мови, орієнтація на
>   встановлення суворих правил дотримання літ. норм (див. Норма мовна),
>   оберігання мови від впливу іншомов. запозичень, очищення її від неліт.
>   явищ (діалектизмів, просторіччя тощо).
>
> To [**filter**](https://dictionary.cambridge.org/dictionary/english/filter) - to appear or happen gradually or to a limited degree.
>
> [**ЦІДИ́ТИ**](https://goroh.pp.ua/%D0%A2%D0%BB%D1%83%D0%BC%D0%B0%D1%87%D0%B5%D0%BD%D0%BD%D1%8F/%D1%86%D1%96%D0%B4%D0%B8%D1%82%D0%B8) - Пропускати рідину через що-небудь (сито, полотно, сітку
>   і т. ін.) для очищення.
>
> [**ВІДСІВА́ТИ**](https://goroh.pp.ua/%D0%A2%D0%BB%D1%83%D0%BC%D0%B0%D1%87%D0%B5%D0%BD%D0%BD%D1%8F/%D0%B2%D1%96%D0%B4%D1%81%D1%96%D0%B2%D0%B0%D1%82%D0%B8) - Просіваючи, відокремлювати що-небудь від чогось.

Якщо **to filter** перекладається як **цідити** чи **сіяти**, то використання слова **процідити** чи **відсіяти** замість **фільтрувати** це пуризм?

1. Припустимо, що є бажання заробити гроші і є виріб, який можна перепродати з гарним прибутком. Закони країни вимагають писати кирилицею. Але людина, що намагається перепродати товар не знає достатньо іноземну мову для перекладу і в цей момент просто пише замість **цідилки** - **фільтр**, тобто просто копіює. Цей виріб добре розповсюджується і люди, що теж не добре знають іноземну мову називають виріб як фільтр, по суті не правильно. Але в той же час успішно ним користуються. Використання слова **фільтр** правильне в цьому випадку?
2. Припустимо, що є нова технологія, яка масово розповсюджується по світу. Її пояснюють на пальцях переважно іноземною мовою, яку до цього, окрім цієї нової технології а також зі знанням іноземної мови на базовому рівні не зустрічали. Тобто усі слова, з якими погано знайомі майбутні спеціалісти автоматично будуть використовувати як терміни. І знову ж таки поширюють такі терміни. Бо це ж спеціялісти так кажуть! Чи буде використання слова **фільтр** в даному випадку правильним?

І це лише два таких випадки. І в усих цих випадках часу на те, щоб розібратися з іноземною мовою просто немає. Для перекладу не використовують знавців обох мов. Усім потрібні гроші. З цим усим треба розібратися, щоб зробити правильно. Але цього не роблять.

Якщо to filter перекладається як **цідити** чи **сіяти**, то використання слова **процідити** чи **відсіяти** це пуризм?

Для людей навіть малюють [іконку](https://fontawesome.com/icons?d=gallery&q=filter) цідилки біля слова **filter**, яке, у випадку з іконкою, перекладається як **відсіяти** чи **процідити** (залежить від даних, які використовуються та вашого розуміння).

Хто визначає крайність вияву турботи? Як називається небажання або неможливість взагалі перекладати іноземні слова? Некомпетентність чи байдужість? Чи правильним є такий підхід для вливання все більшої кількості однакових за значенням слів у мову, замість перекладу та підбору з вже наявних слів?

Основне запитання: Як визначити, чи є пуризмом використання замість слова **фільтр** (**фільтрувати**), наприклад, слово **відсіяти**? Якщо для мене слово **відсіяти** є зрозумілішим (за слово **фільтрувати**) у випадках його використання в словосполученнях "**відсіяти** дані", "**відсіяти** вироби за кольором", "**відсіяти** сукні за розміром", де вироби чи сукні є інформацією, а не певними предметами? Чи стаю я тоді пуристом?

Додатково.

[Відсіяти](https://goroh.pp.ua/%D0%A2%D0%BB%D1%83%D0%BC%D0%B0%D1%87%D0%B5%D0%BD%D0%BD%D1%8F/%D0%B2%D1%96%D0%B4%D1%81%D1%96%D1%8F%D1%82%D0%B8)

> Шляхом відбору усувати, вилучати когось, щось із складу кого-,
>   чого-небудь.
>
> Приклади
>
> Артистові потрібна глибока мудрість для того, щоб без помилок відсіювати від потрібного матеріалу все зайве. (з мемуарної літ.)
>
> Із того величезного масиву інформації, з яким неминуче стикалися в інститутах, Келдиш швидко відсівав усе несуттєве, але досить
>   зацікавлено входив у найдрібніші деталі дійсно нових досліджень. (з
>   публіц. літ.)
>
> – Як вибираєте героїв для телепередачі та як збираєте на них досьє? – Ми складаємо список людей, яких хотіли б бачити. До того ж ще
>   й пропонують когось. Відсіваємо самі, а частина людей відмовляється.
>   (з газ.)
>
> Вислухавши довгу сповідь, відсіявши зайве, нотує [Зоя] в журналі: у Паливоди аварія. (О. Гончар)

Answer (score 3):

Слова "відсіяти" і "відфільтувати" не є синонімами. 
"Відсіяти" вживається тільки в значенні "відкинути об'єкти", а "відфільтувати" може вживатися і в занченні "вибрати об'єкти".
Так що використання слова "відсіяти" як прямого аналога англійського "filter" буде радше не пуризмом, а помилкою.

Натомість слово "відсіяти" чудово підходить для налаштувань пошуку на сайті якогось інтернет-магазину, щоб дати можливість користувачу виключити з пошуку об'єкти з якоюсь характеристикою. Англійською це пишуть часто як "exclude from search". Наприклад:

```
Фільтрувати: [2 сім карти], [RAM >3Gb]
Відсіяти: [ціна > 5000₴]
```

Comment: Насправді слово [«відсіювати»](https://sum20ua.com/Entry/index?wordid=13780&page=447) можуть застосовувати не лише до непотрібної фракції («при товченні вугілля відсіюють пил»), а й до потрібної («відсіяти зерно від полови»). Наскільки я розумію, у первісному значенні відсіюють фракцію з _меншим розміром часточок_ (але це необов'язково гірша фракція, може бути навпаки). Але так, Ви маєте рацію, що _найчастіше_ це слово застосовують саме до непотрібної фракції (і саме таке переносне значення зафіксовано під номером 3 в словнику).

Comment: А ближче до потрібного значення, мабуть, слово [просіяти](http://sum.in.ua/s/prosivaty).

Comment: @Sasha наскільки я зрозумів запитання, автор хотів дізнатися чи варто йому використовувати слова "цідити" та "відсіяти" в інтерфейсах веб сайтів для позначення фільтрів пошуку (чи це не буде пуризмом з якого насміхатимуться)

Comment: Ну, так, я теж так думаю. Я просто спробував трішки вточнити відповідь (мовляв, _відсіяти_, на відміну від _відфільтрувати_, справді найчастіше застосовують саме до непотрібної фракції, але все-таки не завжди).

Comment: Чому це відсіяти і відфільтрувати не є синонімами? Той самий процес сортування за ознакою. В першому випадку за допомогою вітру (воздушного потоку), в іншому - наприклад, з рідини.

Comment: @Skill, мабуть, Ви маєте рацію, що правильніше було б сказати, що це «часткові, а не повні синоніми» (а не «[зовсім] не є синонімами»); я думаю, Volodymyr саме це й мав на увазі.